# firestore update value in array inside doc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking at the firestore docs for hours and still didnt found solution for this case.
I need to add an ammout feature to product my E-commerce app.

data structure :
the main collection is "cart" and the doc is the user email.

here is the current code for add or set a product:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';


export async function addToCart(userMail, itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description) {
    const ammout = 1
    const cartItem = { itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description, ammout }
    if (userMail === undefined) throw console.error('please Login');

    const userDoc = await firebase.firestore().collection("cart").doc(userMail)

    await userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            (async () => {
                    

                await userDoc.update({
                    item: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(cartItem),
                })
            })()
        }
        else {
            (async () => {
                await userDoc.set({
                    item: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(cartItem)
                })
            })()
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be that you are using both `await` and `Promise.then()` in the same function, this could be creating some synchonicity issue, also you don't need to `await` for the `userDoc` variable to be populated, as you can see on the [firestore documentation example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

So basically I would remove all the `async/await` from your code as they are not really needed and the `Promise.then()` on the `.get()` will be enough to ensure synchronicity in your code which could look something like this:

```
export function addToCart(userMail, itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description) {
    const ammout = 1
    const cartItem = { itemId, name, url, price, category, type, description, ammout }
    if (userMail === undefined) throw console.error('please Login');

    const userDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("cart").doc(userMail)

    userDoc.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            userDoc.update({
                item: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(cartItem),
            })
        }
        else {
            userDoc.set({
                item: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(cartItem)
            })
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Thats another issue i will look it up, ty.

Comment: @YanivCode what do you mean with that's another issue?